# Not able to fetch data in one to one related data in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am not able to fetch the Centers Location where as I am able to save and update it it database. Its only fetching where I am facing problem

```
public class Club
{
    public Club()
    {
        this.Memberships = new HashSet<Membership>();
        this.People = new HashSet<Manager>();
        this.Center = new Center();
    }

    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Center")]
    public virtual Center Center { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Manager> People { get; set; }

}
```

My center model

```
public class Center
{       
    [Key,ForeignKey("Club")]
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
}
```

and the index method is

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Clubs.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference to Center is virtual, so it is lazy loaded. Try this instead:

```
return View(db.Clubs.Include(c => c.Center).ToList());
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy

I noticed you're sending your entity model to the view. You may want to look into the viewmodel pattern and automapper. http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201303/Blog/Why-You-Never-Expose-Your-Domain-Model-As-Your-MVC-Model/